# How to manage files in Design team?

Tags: design

Working as a design team would be amazing but, there's a lot of documents, wireframes, user flows and etc. that should be managed. I'm looking for an all in one solution like AXURE to classify my documents for each page. I tried Axure but it has a very bad experience and not working well on my computer. Another solution is using Moqups, Avocode, or other apps like these or using google drive or dropbox beside them for managing manage documents. I want to know about your experiences and recommended solutions. 
Thank you all

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for software recommendations. This can only result in stories about experiences with software but won't give you any methodology to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Hossein, at the core this is a question of how you design the processes within your team. The foundation is that everyone on your team understands your internal process flows, and is willing to support and apply them.

That said, there are some excellent tools out there that are specifically designed to help you manage design documents. One such tool as [Abstract](https://abstract.com), which is comparable to github, but for designers.

As a cloud service, Abstract stores Sketch and Adobe Xd files on the company's servers and provides basic project and access management to manage those files.

We've adopted this service in our design team, and it solved a number of annoying problems that are typically associated with managing individual files, such as versioning (no more `design`, `design v.2`, `design v.2 final`, `design v.2 final update`, etc.).

It also makes it easy for multiple people in a team to work on the same files and to reconcile any conflicts when uploading changes, creating the oh-so important Single Source of Truth for any designs.

I'm not aware of other tools like it, but I'd be surprised if there aren't any. Also, I'm just a happy user and not trying to sell you something. :)

Bottom line: create a solid process, investigate and integrate tools that support that process, optimize — and then iterate.! Just like you'd do with any other design project. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. the Abstract only works with sketch or XD on Mac OS. We use Figma on Windows. So, It's not working for us, But anyway thanks for your time.